# how to remove a specific class of jobs from a sidekiq queue?

Tags: ruby, redis, sidekiq

I've accidentally enqueued a bunch of jobs in Sidekiq. I do not want to wipe my entire Redis store (and reset ALL Sidekiq data and enqueued jobs to nil) but I would like to remove all enqueued jobs that can be identified by a given class. How would I do this?

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224817/delete-redis-hash-values-in-bulk-based-on-the-hash-key-name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These answers were helpful, but didn't answer the original question for me. It's possible those solutions are out of date.

You have to access the job's args and grab it's actual job class within the loop scope. I tried the above and it did not work as expected because `job.klass` does not return what you'd expect it to.

This is what it returns in the terminal currently:

```
queue.each do |job|
  puts job.klass
end

ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper
=> nil
```

So my solution was to dig into the job's arguments like so:

```
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new("job_queue_name")

queue.each do |job|
  puts job.args.first['job_class']
  job.delete if job.args.first['job_class'] == "Things::DoesThatThingJob"
end
```

I'm sure there's a way to write this more elegantly (maybe with a select?)
But it's readable.
Hope I was able to help others like me that were looking for something like this.

Comment: This looks great and thanks for useful enhancements. I've made this the official answer.

Comment: Glad I was able to help out @Ivar

Comment: I tried `jobs.args.first['job_class']` but it didn't work. @Ivar 's answer using `job.klass` works fine. Also, according to Sidekiq API doc, job.klass should be the right solution.

Answer (score 10):

I found the [Sidekiq API](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#queue) provides an easy way to do what I need:

```
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new(queue_name)
queue.each do |job|
    puts job.klass
    job.delete if job.klass == job_class
end
```

Answer (score 1):

try a method like this in a helper module, where `klass` is the Worker class.

```
 def self.delete_jobs_for_worker(klass)

  jobs = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new
  jobs.select do |job|
    job.klass == 'Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass' &&
        ((job_klass, job_method, args) = YAML.load(job.args[0])) &&
        job_klass == klass 
  end.map(&:delete)

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The code sample you provided led me to the doc pages I had missed, which had the information I needed to perform exactly what was required.