# Redis Python - how to delete all keys according to a specific pattern In python, without python iterating

Tags: python, django, redis, django-cache, redis-py

I'm writing a django management command to handle some of our redis caching. Basically, I need to choose all keys, that confirm to a certain pattern (for example: "prefix:*") and delete them.

I know I can use the cli to do that:

```
redis-cli KEYS "prefix:*" | xargs redis-cli DEL
```

But I need to do this from within the app. So I need to use the python binding (I'm using py-redis). I have tried feeding a list into delete, but it fails:

```
from common.redis_client import get_redis_client
cache = get_redis_client()
x = cache.keys('prefix:*') 

x == ['prefix:key1','prefix:key2'] # True
```

# And now

```
cache.delete(x)
```

# returns 0 . nothing is deleted

I know I can iterate over x:

```
for key in x:
   cache.delete(key)
```

But that would be losing redis awesome speed and misusing its capabilities. Is there a pythonic solution with py-redis, without iteration and/or the cli?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think the

```
 for key in x: cache.delete(key)
```

is pretty good and concise.  `delete` really wants one key at a time, so you have to loop.

Otherwise, this [previous question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis) points you to a lua-based solution.

Comment: Using redis-python package you can do that such way:

`cache.delete(*keys)`

Answer (score 64):

Use SCAN iterators: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis

```
for key in r.scan_iter("prefix:*"):
    r.delete(key)
```

Comment: django-redis implements delete_pattern which does something very similar to this, see https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis/blob/master/django_redis/client/default.py#L264 .

Comment: I cannot find `scan_iter` in the Redis Python documentation. Has it been removed?

Answer (score 40):

Here is a full working example using [py-redis](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
from redis import StrictRedis
cache = StrictRedis()

def clear_ns(ns):
    """
    Clears a namespace
    :param ns: str, namespace i.e your:prefix
    :return: int, cleared keys
    """
    count = 0
    ns_keys = ns + '*'
    for key in cache.scan_iter(ns_keys):
        cache.delete(key)
        count += 1
    return count
```

You can also do `scan_iter` to get all the keys into memory, and then pass all the keys to `delete` for a bulk delete but may take a good chunk of memory for larger namespaces. So probably best to run a `delete` for each key.

Cheers!

UPDATE:

Since writing the answer, I started using pipelining feature of redis to send all commands in one request and avoid network latency:

```
from redis import StrictRedis
cache = StrictRedis()

def clear_cache_ns(ns):
    """
    Clears a namespace in redis cache.
    This may be very time consuming.
    :param ns: str, namespace i.e your:prefix*
    :return: int, num cleared keys
    """
    count = 0
    pipe = cache.pipeline()
    for key in cache.scan_iter(ns):
        pipe.delete(key)
        count += 1
    pipe.execute()
    return count
```

UPDATE2 (Best Performing):

If you use `scan` instead of `scan_iter`, you can control the chunk size and iterate through the cursor using your own logic. This also seems to be a lot faster, especially when dealing with many keys. If you add pipelining to this you will get a bit of a performance boost, 10-25% depending on chunk size, at the cost of memory usage since you will not send the execute command to Redis until everything is generated. So I stuck with scan:

```
from redis import StrictRedis
cache = StrictRedis()
CHUNK_SIZE = 5000

def clear_ns(ns):
    """
    Clears a namespace
    :param ns: str, namespace i.e your:prefix
    :return: int, cleared keys
    """
    cursor = '0'
    ns_keys = ns + '*'
    while cursor != 0:
        cursor, keys = cache.scan(cursor=cursor, match=ns_keys, count=CHUNK_SIZE)
        if keys:
            cache.delete(*keys)

    return True
```

Here are some benchmarks:

5k chunks using a busy Redis cluster:

```
Done removing using scan in 4.49929285049
Done removing using scan_iter in 98.4856731892
Done removing using scan_iter & pipe in 66.8833789825
Done removing using scan & pipe in 3.20298910141
```

5k chunks and a small idle dev redis (localhost):

```
Done removing using scan in 1.26654982567
Done removing using scan_iter in 13.5976779461
Done removing using scan_iter & pipe in 4.66061878204
Done removing using scan & pipe in 1.13942599297
```

Comment: I provided a full working example. Also would like others to comment on scan_iter vs bulk delete

Comment: Great answer, this should be the correct answer. Today I actually needed this answer myself and am preferring your answer above mine. Although some minor errors in your example, like no ns_keys variable in your first update, and :: within your second update.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually don't use scanning in prod because its so slow, instead I end up caching every key in the namespace and doing a bulk delete that way.  Seems like overkill I know but the performance is best because you don't have to scan cache at all.

Comment: FYI, there's a syntax error on line 13 of your third example; you have two colons (:) at the end of your while condition.

Comment: UPDATE2 is priceless in production (default `chunk_size` would be order of magnitude slower!): chunk_size:execute_time: 5:1m 44.8s 50:17.0s 500:7.3s 5000:Timeout reading from socket

Comment: Be very careful when using high values of `chunk_size` in PRD, increase size slowly, starting from 1, or else you can easily cause cache read timeouts! Chunk size has direct impact on `redis-server` CPU utilization (e.g. reaching 90% with `chunk_size` of 170 for a 30+ gig database with millions of keys, where `scan`+`delete` takes about 4 minutes for this maximum safe chunk).

Comment: It all depends on your instance size, fine tuning will be required, 5k chunk size was perfect for me.

Comment: The typing between `cursor = '0'` and `while cursor != 0` is awkward. You could use a `cursor = None` and `cache.scan(cursor=cursor or 0, ...)` to make it slightly better

Comment: Note that even when this answer was written in 2017, redis-py has allowed you to provide a chunksize to `scan_iter`. You don't have to manage the cursor yourself. (https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/25c46abdebbf60c599e6b9fcd7a4532bd8272a55/redis/client.py#L1479-L1492)

Answer (score 11):

From the [Documentation](http://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.delete)

> ```
> delete(*names)
>     Delete one or more keys specified by names
> ```

This just wants an argument per key to delete and then it will tell you how many of them were found and deleted.

In the case of your code above I believe you can just do:

```
    redis.delete(*x)
```

But I will admit I am new to python and I just do:

```
    deleted_count = redis.delete('key1', 'key2')
```

Answer (score 9):

Btw, for the django-redis you can use the following (from https://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/):

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.delete_pattern("foo_*")
```

Comment: This question pertains to redis, so django cache framework is out of scope.

Answer (score 7):

`cache.delete(*keys)` solution of Dirk works fine, but make sure keys isn't empty to avoid a `redis.exceptions.ResponseError: wrong number of arguments for 'del' command`.

If you are sure that you will always get a result: `cache.delete(*cache.keys('prefix:*') )`

Comment: Don't use `cache.keys()` in prod, its intended for debugging: https://redis.io/commands/keys

Answer (score 6):

You can use a specific pattern to match all keys and delete them:

```
import redis
client = redis.Redis(host='192.168.1.106', port=6379,
                password='pass', decode_responses=True)
for key in client.keys('prefix:*'):
    client.delete(key)
```

Answer (score 4):

According to my test, it will costs too much time if I use `scan_iter` solution (as [Alex Toderita wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37135158/1333493)).

Therefore, I prefer to use:

```
from redis.connection import ResponseError

try:
    redis_obj.eval('''return redis.call('del', unpack(redis.call('keys', ARGV[1])))''', 0, 'prefix:*')
except ResponseError:
    pass
```

The `prefix:*` is the pattern.

---

refers to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16974060

Answer (score 0):

Use delete_pattern: https://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.delete_pattern("prefix:*")
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested by @radtek is not working for me, since the keys are getting deleted while iterating, which leads to unexpected behavior. Here's an example:

```py
from redis import StrictRedis
cache = StrictRedis()

for i in range(0, 10000):
    cache.set(f'test_{i}', 1)


cursor = '0'
SCAN_BATCH_SIZE = 5000
while cursor != 0:
    cursor, keys = self._redis.scan(cursor=cursor, match='test_*', count=SCAN_BATCH_SIZE)
    if keys:
        cache.delete(*keys)


## Iteration 1
# cursor=5000, keys=['test_0', .... , 'test_4999']
# keys will get deleted

## Iteration 2
# cursor=0, keys=[]
# No remaining keys are found reason being, there are just the 
# 5000 entries left post deletion and the cursor position is already 
# at 5000. Hence, no keys are returned.
```

You can use redis pipeline in order to solve this issue as mentioned below:

```py
from redis import StrictRedis
cache = StrictRedis()

for i in range(0, 10000):
    cache.set(f'test_{i}', 1)


pipe = cache.pipeline()
cursor = None
SCAN_BATCH_SIZE = 5000
while cursor != 0:
    cursor, keys = self._redis.scan(cursor=cursor or 0, match='test_*', count=SCAN_BATCH_SIZE)
    if keys:
        pipe.delete(*keys)
pipe.execute()
```