# How to remove all elements in Redis

Tags: python, redis

How to remove all elements in Redis? I tried with the following snippet code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52292379/3702377) but didn't work.

I've such this:

```
import redis
from pprint import pprint

cli = redis.Redis('localhost')

dict_ = {  # dummy
    'tags': {'module': 'voltage', 'station': 'SNMP'},
    'metric_name': 'voltage',
    'value': 222,
    'time': '2018-11-13T15:25:09'
}
cli.hmset("pythonDict", dict_)

for key in cli.keys('prefix:*'):  # Didn't work.
    cli.delete(key)

pprint(cli.hgetall("pythonDict"))
```

Still, the previous data appeared from `dict_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing in Redis an object (`dict_`) under the key called 'pythonDict'. Just call `cli.delete("pythonDict")` to delete it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.

Comment: What is the difference between this line and `cli.flushall()` or `cli.flushdb()`?

Comment: The first deletes all databases, the other just the currently-selected database. The docs are at https://redis.io/commands