# Removing hash attribute in redis with wildcard

Tags: python, redis, key-value, nosql

In redis, we can use wildcard like,

`KEYS foo*`  -> to find keys.

Now I want to delete particular field of hashmap using wildcard. Consider following eg.
creating hashmap

```
 HMSET myhash f "g" field1 "Hello" field2 "World"
```

now I want to delete key using wildcard like

```
 DEL myha*
```

Is it possible?

Also I want to delete particular field from SET using wildcard like

```
DEL myhash field*
```

Is this also possible?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: For DEL myha*, you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis . But for DEL myhash field*, I'm afraid you need a script to do that.

Comment: @BrandonGao thnx man for taking interest. So it is possible. Can you give any example or resource link?

Comment: you can refer to the original redis doc to write the script. But I think you need to use HDEL for your second question.

Comment: @BrandonGao thnk u so much

Comment: Use SCAN and HSCAN. Don't use KEYS (at all!) unless there are very few keys in total. The results from SCAN and HSCAN can be put in a Lua script call, serialized as msgpack, to delete per batch. Suggested batch size: 1000.

Answer (score 2):

To delete particular fields from SET using wildcards you can use this LUA script:

```
-- ARGV[1] - hash key
-- ARGV[1] - lua pattern 
local fields = redis.call("HKEYS", ARGV[1]);
local retVal = {};
for key, value in pairs(fields) do
    if (string.match(value, ARGV[2])) then
        table.insert(retVal, value);
        redis.call("HDEL", ARGV[1], value);
    end
end

return retVal;
```

This script has complexity **O(n)**. Script return deleted fields matched by given pattern. Look at [string.match tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial) to lua pattern matching features.

Sample usage in `PHP` with `phpredis`:

```
$r = new Redis();
$r->connect('127.0.0.1');

for ($i = 1; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $r->hSet('myhash', 'aaa' . mt_rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX), 1);
}
$r->hSet('myhash', 'bad', 1);

$script = <<< SCR
    local fields = redis.call("HKEYS", ARGV[1]);
    local retVal = {};
    for key, value in pairs(fields) do
        if (string.match(value, ARGV[2])) then
            table.insert(retVal, value);
            redis.call("HDEL", ARGV[1], value);
        end
    end

    return retVal;
SCR;

var_dump($r->eval($script, ['myhash', '^b.+']));
```