# Is there any way implement a simple Redis DEL on matching keys using SCAN?

Tags: redis

Lots of folks use redis for simple key/value cache store.  Sometimes you just want to kill off a subset of your keys.

The common question I see everywhere is "How do I do a `DEL prefix*`".

For various reasons, Redis doesn't currently have this functionality and I get the vibe they have strong fundamental position against such a feature it will likely never happen.

As far as I know, there are a number of work-arounds like this piping fun on the command line:

```
 redis-cli  KEYS "prefix:*" | xargs redis-cli  DEL
```

Or using an `EVAL`:

```
 EVAL "local keys = redis.call('keys', ARGV[1]) \n for i=1,#keys,5000 do \n redis.call('del', unpack(keys, i, math.min(i+4999, #keys))) \n end \n return keys" 0 prefix:*
```

However, I've learned from folks on the Redis github project that using `KEYS *` is expensive and bad practice--with the suggestion that it's to be avoided on production systems: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2042

The indication is a better way to match key patterns is via `SCAN`

```
 SCAN 0 MATCH prefix:*
```

Does anyone know a way within redis to use `SCAN` in conjunction with `DEL` to achieve at least a mock of the holy grail, a simple `DEL prefix:*`?

Or must you use `SCAN` in a separate program/shell script, then parse the results and issue DEL on the keys in a loop or such?

Comment: I doubt it that you'll find a better solution in SO - the GH folks usually know best ;) in any case, here's a bash script i made a while ago https://gist.github.com/itamarhaber/11126830

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/4006324/1202461

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23399125/1449151