# remove all matching keys

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I want to remove all keys matching SomePrefix* from my Redis. Is it possible ?
I see only m_connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase().KeyDelete() but not KeyMatch() or GetAllKeys() within the library.

Preferably not Lua scripting such as [link by Leonid Beschastny](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4006324/1202461)

I want to use that on initialization of web application for development state of the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to atomically delete keys matching a pattern using Redis](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4006324/1202461).

Comment: I know that but i thought there is easier usage rather than lua within stackexchange.redis client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SE.Redis directly mimics the features exposed by the server. The server does not have a "delete keys matching this pattern" feature. It does have "scan for keys matching this pattern" (via `GetServer().GetKeys(...)`), and it has "delete this key / these keys" (via `GetDatabase.KeyDelete(...)`). You could iterate in batches over the matching keys, deleting each batch in turn. Because you can pipeline requests, you don't pay latency per batch.

As an alternative implementation: partition the data by numeric database (`select`) or server, and use `flushdb` / `flush`.

Comment: You must be joking, i should ask developer of this thing ;-) ... Thanks

Comment: @eugeneK note: I added an alternative option in an edit.