# How can we delete table items from redis?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack.redis

[image]

I want all idbclients, whats it script form redis cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://redis.io/commands where you'll find all commands. It's worth to have a good feeling for them before using a GUI. Selecting a number of keys with a pattern is documented at http://redis.io/commands/keys.

So in your case simply call **`keys urn:idbclients:*`** in the CLI (or if you're scripting then run this command from inside your script using your client library).

Comment: Just to be clear - Redis doesn't have a single command to delete keys based on a pattern so scripting is the way to do it. For an example of such a script (which uses the safer SCAN instead of KEYS) see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23399125/3160475