# Redis wildcard delete

Tags: c#, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using the the stackexchange redis provider and I'm trying to delete all keys starting with a certain key.

```
private readonly Lazy<IEnumerable<IServer>> allServers = new Lazy<IEnumerable<IServer>>(() => Connection.GetEndPoints().Select(s => Connection.GetServer(s)));
private const int DbId = 1;
private const int ScanPageSize = 1 << 14;

public void RemoveByPattern(string pattern)
{
    var keys = this.AllServers.Value.SelectMany(x => x.Keys(DbId, pattern + "*", ScanPageSize)).Distinct().ToArray();
    if (!keys.Any())
        return;
    this.Database.KeyDelete(keys);
}
```

^^ This is the method I've come up which works fine most of the time. But as soon as I put a bit of load on the system I'm getting errors that look like this:

```
  System.TimeoutException: Timeout performing SCAN, inst: 0, mgr: Inactive, queue: 11, qu=11, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0/1, in=0/0
     at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl (StackExchange.Redis.StrongName, Version=1.0.316.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c219ff1ca8c2ce46)
     at StackExchange.Redis.RedisServer.ExecuteSync (StackExchange.Redis.StrongName, Version=1.0.316.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c219ff1ca8c2ce46)
     at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase+CursorEnumerable`1.GetNextPageSync (StackExchange.Redis.StrongName, Version=1.0.316.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c219ff1ca8c2ce46)
     at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase+CursorEnumerable`1+CursorEnumerator.MoveNext (StackExchange.Redis.StrongName, Version=1.0.316.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c219ff1ca8c2ce46)
     at System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>d__1`2.MoveNext (System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
     at System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctIterator>d__1`1.MoveNext (System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
     at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor (System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray (System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
     at Test.RedisCacheManager.RemoveByPattern (TestApplication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?
I know that if I knew about all the keys on the .net side i could avoid the scan. But unfortunately that's not particularly easy in my case.

Comment: Also note your code is not cluster-compatible. You should consider using a tagging mechanism to maintain the relation between the keys, like in [CachingFramework.Redis](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis)

Comment: Please check my asnwer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094938/azure-cache-datacache-style-regions-in-redis/34414377#34414377) to delete keys by wildcard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redis Stack Exchange how to delete or get keys by pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488830/redis-stack-exchange-how-to-delete-or-get-keys-by-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36631784/1056566). You can use the following with StackExchange.Redis.StrongName v1.0.488.

```
        foreach (var ep in _muxer.GetEndPoints())
        {
            var server = _muxer.GetServer(ep);
            var keys = server.Keys(database: _redisDatabase, pattern: pattern + "*").ToArray();
            _db.KeyDeleteAsync(keys);
        }
```

`_muxer` is instance of `ConnectionMultiplexer`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing *by pattern* you should be able to store partial keys or involved keys in some *set* and then *scan* it (i.e. `sscan`)  using pages to drop the global keyspace keys.

Don't try to remove thousands of keys in a single pass: remember Redis is a single-threaded solution, and your removal will block the entire Redis server.

Comment: Any idea on how about doing that in c#?

Comment: @Sam7 Whenever you add a key that you want to remove later in the global space, you create a set using `IDatabase.SetAdd` or `IDatabaseAsync.SetAddAsync`

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to do what you want, but I agree with @Matías in that you need to store the keys you want to remove later in a SET.

If you are running a standalone Redis the most reliable way will be to do the Add/Remove operations in a Lua Script. But if you plan to have a Redis cluster, you will have to do it client-side.

For example:

```
public void SetValue(string key, string value)
{
    var batch = db.CreateBatch(); // You can use a transaction with CreateTransaction() if you are not in a cluster.
    batch.StringSetAsync(key, value);
    batch.SetAddAsync("to remove", key);
    batch.Execute();
}
public void RemoveAll()
{
    var item = db.SetPop("to remove");
    while (item.HasValue)
    {
        db.KeyDelete(item.ToString());
        item = db.SetPop("to remove");
    }
}
```