# How to delete the specified fields with the same prefix in redis

Tags: redis, prefix

Now I have lots of data in redis and each key has a few fields. I want the delete all the field with the same prefix like "one". And other fields withe different prefix like "two" or "three" should not be affected.

Does redis support this naturally and how can execute the command? Or which is the easily way for me to write the script to achieve this?

Comment: Look at the following for different methods to do that, depending on what you want to ensure (atomicity vs. performance): http://stackoverflow.com/a/23399125/3160475

Comment: Thanks @ItamarHaber I will only clean the data for one time. But actually I just want to delete some prefix fields but not the entire key.

Comment: If you don't know the specific key names, use SCAN to get them. For each key, use HSCAN and delete per your pattern.

Comment: Thanks all and I have written a python script to get all data and delete the specified ones.