# How to delete keys matching a certain pattern in redis

Tags: redis, redis-cli

How to delete keys matching a certain pattern in redis using redis-cli. I would like to delete all foo's from the following list.

```
KEYS *

foo:1
foo:2
bar:1
foo:3
bar:2
foo:4
```

Comment: There are multiple answered questions on the same subject, e.g http://stackoverflow.com/a/23399125/3160475

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to atomically delete keys matching a pattern using Redis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis)

Comment: nice solution, even for large sets > 1000 keys.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis#comment39607023_16974060

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment on the question, there are many other answers to this here already. Definitely read the one linked above if you are thinking about doing this in a production sever.

The one I found most useful for occasional command-line cleanup was:

`redis-cli KEYS "*" | xargs redis-cli DEL`

from ["How to atomically delete keys matching a pattern using Redis"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis/4006575).

Comment: I would use "redis-cli --scan" instead of KEYS. Especially in live environment. Use of KEYS is not recommended.

Comment: I am not able to delete from remote host using `-h` as host.

Comment: Also, just to clarify on what Philip said, It should be redis-cli --scan --pattern "*" if you don't put pattern it'll just select all keys.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to delete thousands of keys by pattern after some searches I found these points:

- if you have more than one db on redis you should determine the database using `-n [number]`
- if you have a few keys use `del` but if there are thousands or millions of keys it's better to use `unlink` because **unlink is non-blocking** while del is blocking, for more information visit this page [unlink vs del](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818371/is-the-unlink-command-always-better-than-del-command)
- also `keys` are like del and is blocking

so I used this code to delete keys by pattern:

```
 redis-cli -n 2 --scan --pattern '[your pattern]' | xargs redis-cli -n 2 unlink
```

Comment: I am getting `(error) CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot` I am using following to delete pattern `hi*` form cluster `redis-cli -u redis://localhost:6379 --scan --pattern 'hi*' | xargs redis-cli -u redis://localhost:6379 DEL`

Comment: hi @roottraveller I have no idea that where is the problem, but I searched a bit and found this link check if it works for you or not https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042629/redis-cross-slot-error

Comment: @roottraveller I had the same issue with redis cluster. One solution is to basically delete keys one by one, but using `redis-cli --pipe` to speed things up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66179509/4256475

Answer (score 2):

If someone want to do same operation in AWS Elasticache redis, then you can connect with SSH to your EC2 server which is supposed to access AWS Redis server then you can use below command.

```
redis-cli -h <HOST> -p <PORT> --scan --pattern "patter*n" | xargs redis-cli -h <HOST> -p <PORT> unlink
```

Replace Host and port with AWS redis server host and port.

Also ***if your redis setup needs password authentication*** then use,

```
redis-cli -h <HOST> -p <PORT> -a <PASSWORD> --scan --pattern "patter*n" | xargs redis-cli -h <HOST> -p <PORT> -a <PASSWORD> unlink
```

Replace Host, port and password with AWS redis server host, port and password.

You can also use above commands for localhost.