# Redis Cross Slot error

Tags: redis

I am trying to insert multiple key/values at once on Redis (some values are sets, some are hashes) and I get this error: `ERR CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot`.

I'm not doing this from `redis-cli` but from some Go code that needs to write multiple key/values to a redis cluster. I see other places in the code where multiple key values are done this way and I don't understand why mine don't work.  What are the hash requirements to not have this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In a cluster topology, the keyspace is divided into hash slots. Different nodes will hold a subset of hash slots.

Multiple keys operations, transactions, or Lua scripts involving multiple keys are allowed only if all the keys involved are in hash slots belonging to the same node.

> Redis Cluster implements all the single key commands available in the
>   non-distributed version of Redis. Commands performing complex
>   multi-key operations like Set type unions or intersections are
>   implemented as well as long as the keys all belong to the same node.

You can force the keys to belong to the same node by using [Hash Tags](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-hash-tags)

Comment: thanks, I didnt know about the {} pattern, this is why it works on the other part of the code

Comment: hi, i m using resid for job queue processing using nodejs kue module, my problem  is, its working with localthost connection, and now i made my redis dabase in aws elastic cache, for live use, when i connect to live redis and run the jobs its showing me this error ReplyError: CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot,  plase help me

Comment: It solved my error, thank you and here is helpful link as well https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elasticache-crossslot-keys-error-redis/

Comment: Actually it is about the SAME keyslot.  Same node is just a consequence of this.

Answer (score 8):

> ERR CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot

As the error message suggests, only if all of the keys belong to same slot will the operation succeed. Otherwise, you will see this failure message. This error would be seen even though both/all slots belongs to the same node. The check is very strict and, as per the code, all keys should hash to same slot.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I created a Redis cluster via AWS.
The issue was fixed when I disabled  cluster mode and ran the Redis with one single node