# How to send multiple commands to Redis cluster using StackExchange.Redis library

Tags: stackexchange.redis

I've spent many days trying to send mulitple commands to redis cluster using different approach but still no solutions. This approach is using StachExchange. i have a redis cluster with 3 masters with 1 slave each. ports 30001, 30002 and 30003 are the masters

here is my code

```
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System;

namespace redis
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("192.168.1.100:30001,192.168.1.100:30002,192.168.1.100:30003,connectTimeout=1000");
            IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();

            db.StringSet("mykey", "abcdefg");

            db.StringSet("mykey1", "11111");
            db.StringSet("mykey2", "2222");

            string value2 = db.StringGet("mykey2");
            Console.WriteLine(value2);
        }
    }
}
```

and below is the error

```
Unhandled Exception: StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: Endpoint 127.0.0.1:30003 serving hashslot 14687 is not reachable at this point of time. Please check connectTimeout value. If it is low, try increasing it to give the ConnectionMultiplexer a chance to recover from the network disconnect.
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.StringSet(RedisKey key, RedisValue value, Nullable`1 expiry, When when, CommandFlags flags)
   at redis.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\xxxx\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\redis\redis\Program.cs:line 31
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I also did some experiment by running commands directly to redis cli and **i notice redirection after sending commands which i think is causing the problem**

before sending the commands i did flushall to my masters 30001, 30002 and 30003

```
xxxx@RedisServer:~/cluster-test/30003$ redis-cli -c -p 30001
127.0.0.1:30001> set mykey "abcdefg"
-> Redirected to slot [14687] located at 127.0.0.1:30003
OK
127.0.0.1:30003> set mykey1 "11111"
-> Redirected to slot [1860] located at 127.0.0.1:30001
OK
127.0.0.1:30001> set mykey2 "2222"
-> Redirected to slot [14119] located at 127.0.0.1:30003
OK
127.0.0.1:30003> get mykey
"abcdefg"
127.0.0.1:30003> get mykey1
-> Redirected to slot [1860] located at 127.0.0.1:30001
"11111"
127.0.0.1:30001> get mykey2
-> Redirected to slot [14119] located at 127.0.0.1:30003
"2222"
127.0.0.1:30003>
```

i need help in sending those commands to redis cluster. the code runs perfectly fine on non-cluster btw

**12/4 updates**

```
Endpoint 127.0.0.1:30003 serving hashslot 14687 is not reachable at...
```

looking at the above error code, i changed my connection to connect only to port 30003

```
 ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("192.168.1.100:30003,connectTimeout=1000");
            IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
            db.StringSet("mykey", "abcdefg");
```

and it was able to connect and set the *mykey*

```
127.0.0.1:30003> get mykey
"abcdefg"
```

**another test**

this time i set a debug in line where *mykey1* is

```
 ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("192.168.1.100:30003,connectTimeout=1000");
            IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
            db.StringSet("mykey", "abcdefg");
            db.StringSet("mykey1", "11111");
```

*mykey* line is successful bec we are connecting to the node where *mykey*'s hashslot belongs
But *mykey1* has an exeption bec it's hashslot belongs to 30001 node

```
occurred in StackExchange.Redis.dll

Additional information: Endpoint 127.0.0.1:30001 serving hashslot 1860 is not reachable at this point of time. Please check connectTimeout value. If it is low, try increasing it to give the ConnectionMultiplexer a chance to recover from the network disconnect.
```

**i think the problem is StackExchange.Redis client is not able to know which hashlot the key belongs bec every key in redis cluster has corresponding hashlot which belongs to specific master node**

**another test**

*mykey* belongs to 30003, so i put 192.168.1.100:30003 in the connection string first
then i know that *mykey1* belongs to 192.168.1.100:30001 so i put it right after 30003

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("192.168.1.100:30003,192.168.1.100:30001,connectTimeout=1000");
            IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
            db.StringSet("mykey", "abcdefg");
            db.StringSet("mykey1", "11111");
```

the result after debugging, the exception below occurs when setting *mykey*

```
An unhandled exception of type 'StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException' occurred in StackExchange.Redis.dll

Additional information: Endpoint 127.0.0.1:30003 serving hashslot 14687 is not reachable at this point of time. Please check connectTimeout value. If it is low, try increasing it to give the ConnectionMultiplexer a chance to recover
```

this result showed me that the client is using 192.168.1.100:30001, it used the last host in the connection

Comment: Can you re-run your tests adding a `Thread.Sleep(5000)` after the `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect`?

Comment: Which version of the library are you using?

Comment: this is my package

<package id="StackExchange.Redis" version="1.1.608" targetFramework="net452" />

I've also added Thread.Sleep(5000) after ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect but it only added 5 second delay then produces 'StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException' in db.StringSet("mykey", "abcdefg");

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes. All the bits are there. However, the library *authors* don't currently use cluster (because it is missing a DC-centric feature that is on the roadmap for 4.2). To help with testing, we have recently improved our access to cluster configs; I will try to run your sample through that. However, it would actually be interesting to me if you could run the *exact same test* between the library and the command-line - in your example here, the keys are actually different. I'd love to see what it says for the exact same keys.

Comment: thanks for your time. i've re-run my code keys to command-line keys

Comment: Thanks. The good news, at least, is that it got all the sharding and resolution stuff right. The bad news is obviously that it couldn't talk to the server. I do not know why off the top of my head. But we're actively ramping up our cluster tests and support, which might help if there is an inherent problem. You could also try passing a text-writer in to the connect API to see what it says.

Comment: thanks mark, i did another tests. please see 12/4 updates above. i hope this is help

Comment: "i think the problem is StackExchange.Redis client is not able to know which hashlot the key belongs bec every key in redis cluster has corresponding hashlot which belongs to specific master node" - no it knows. Even if you only put one server in the config, it knows. It just couldn't find it. I need to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

This could be occurring due to cross slot error.

Take a look: [Redis Cross Slot error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042629/redis-cross-slot-error)