Redis Keys show up in local environment but not in Cluster
I am writing a program which creates and then uses Redis keys for message sorting. When i try to do this using my local Redis instance i can see that the keys are created and the program works fine. But when I try to do this using a Redis Cluster I am not able to view the keys on the cluster.
This is how i connect to the cluster -
constructor() {
        const clusterEndpoints = [{ host: env.REDIS_ENDPOINT, port: parseInt(env.REDIS_PORT) }];
        const redisPassword = env.REDIS_PASSWORD;

        const sslOptions = {
            tls: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false,
                minVersion: 'TLSv1.2' as const,
            },
        };

        const clusterOptions: ClusterOptions = {
            redisOptions: {
                password: redisPassword,
                ...sslOptions,
            },
        };

        this.client = new Redis.Cluster(clusterEndpoints, clusterOptions);

        // Log connection success
        this.client.on('connect', () => {
            logger.info('Successfully connected to Redis cluster at:', clusterEndpoints);
        });
    }

this established connection is then used by the sorting function-
    public async sortMessage(message: Message, messageTimestamp: number): Promise<number | null> {
        try {
            const heapKey = `{message_heap}`;
            const lastTsKey = `{message_heap}:last_ts`;
            const brandLastTsKey = `{message_heap}:brand_last_ts`;
            const brandCntKey = `{message_heap}:brand_count`;

            await this.client.eval(
                this.insertScript,
                4, // Number of keys
                lastTsKey,
                brandLastTsKey,
                brandCntKey,
                heapKey,
                String(messageTimestamp),
                String(limit),
                JSON.stringify(message),
            );

            return messageTimestamp;
        } catch (error) {
            logger.error('Error sorting message:', error);
            return null;
        }
    }

which in turn calls a lua script to do the redis functionality. I don't think the lua script is the issue as the Redis operations work fine locally.
I can verify that I can connect to the cluster fine. I also have permissions to execute commands and read/write keys on the cluster. I also forced the keys to be in the same hash slot by using the '{}' around 'message_heap'
I tried connecting to the Redis Cluster and trying to locate the keys using GET <key_name> for the string keys. I can confirm the there is a master node with a slave replica on the Redis cluster, so it shouldn't be an issue that I am hitting the wrong node.
I want to be able to see the keys pop up on the Cluster with their associated values when i try locating them using redis-cli, which i don't see happening currently.
This is how i connect to the cluster-
redis-cli -h <host> -p 6379 -a <password> --tls --no-aut
h-warning --insecure -c


https://stackoverflow.com/a/38042895/171006

redis database is right?
// try it
use 0;
keys *

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
