# Is the UNLINK command always better than DEL command?

Tags: redis, blocking, nonblocking

In Redis 4.0, there is a new command [UNLINK](https://redis.io/commands/unlink) to delete the keys in Redis memory.

> This command is very similar to DEL: it removes the specified keys.
>   Just like DEL a key is ignored if it does not exist. However the
>   **command performs the actual memory reclaiming in a different thread**,
>   **so it is not blocking, while DEL is**. This is where the command name
>   comes from: the command just unlinks the keys from the keyspace. The
>   actual removal will happen later asynchronously.

So one can always (100% times) use UNLINK instead of [DEL](https://redis.io/commands/del) as UNLINK is nonblocking, unlike DEL, right?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Before discussing which one is better, let's take a look at the difference between these commands. Both `DEL` and `UNLINK` free the key part in blocking mode. And the difference is the way they free the value part.

`DEL` always frees the value part in blocking mode. However, if the value is too large, e.g. too many allocations for a large `LIST` or `HASH`, it blocks Redis for a long time. In order to solve the problem, Redis implements the `UNLINK` command, i.e. an 'non-blocking' delete.

In fact, `UNLINK` is **NOT always non-blocking/async**. If the value is small, e.g. the size of `LIST` or `HASH` is less than `64`, the value will be freed immediately. In this way, `UNLINK` is almost the same as `DEL`, except that it costs a few more function calls than `DEL`. However, if the value is large, Redis puts the value into a list, and the value will be freed by another thread i.e. the non-blocking free. In this way, the main thread has to do some synchronization with the background thread, and that's also a cost.

In a conclusion, if the value is small, `DEL` is at least, as good as `UNLINK`. If value is very large, e.g. `LIST` with thousands or millions of items, `UNLINK` is much better than `DEL`. You can always safely replace `DEL` with `UNLINK`. However, if you find the thread synchronization becomes a problem (multi-threading is always a headache), you can rollback to `DEL`.

**UPDATE:**

Since Redis 6.0, there's a new configuration: ***lazyfree-lazy-user-del***. You can set it to be *yes*, and Redis will run the `DEL` command as if running a `UNLINK` command.

Comment: >> if you find the thread synchronization becomes a problem <<
How would you know when this is a problem?

Comment: Normally it won't be a problem. However, for each async delete, the background thread needs to get the lock twice, and the foreground (main) thread needs to get the lock once. That might be a problem, e.g. context switch, locking. IMHO, if you find `UNLINK` is slow (again, normally it's won't), you can replace it with `DEL`, and do some benchmark.

Comment: And for a single key how about I set the expire to 0. Will that be faster?

Comment: @Ultrablendz If you set expire to 0, Redis will delete the key immediately. By default, it deletes the key synchronously, and it will block Redis. However, you can set the `lazyfree_lazy_expire` config to `yes`, so that Redis will delete the key asynchronously, which won't block.

Answer (score 14):

YES. please have a read on **[Lazy Redis is better Redis](http://antirez.com/news/93)** from antirez. But the reason is not that the unlink is nonblocking command. The reason is unlink is smarter than del.

> UNLINK is a smart command: it calculates the deallocation cost of an object, and if it is very small it will just do what DEL is supposed to do and free the object ASAP. Otherwise the object is sent to the background queue for processing.

Also, I think the more fast way is we do the decision for redis: using DEL for small key, using UNLINK for a huge key such as big list or set. We can decrease the needless calculation of redis.