# How to delete keys matching a pattern in Redis Cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have tried method in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis), but it does not work since I'm working  in cluster mode, and redis told me:

> (error) CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot

Comment: Some folks have suggested using Eval as an option; but i haven't been able to find a good example using Eval. Any leads? An example for some golang redis-client library would be even better.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Answers for that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis) try to remove multiple keys in a single `DEL`. However, keys matching the given pattern might NOT locate in the same slot, and Redis Cluster DOES NOT support multiple-key command if these keys don't belong to the same slot. That's why you get the error message.

In order to fix this problem, you need to `DEL` these keys one-by-one:

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern "foo*" |xargs -L 1 redis-cli del
```

The `-L` option for `xargs` command specifies the number of keys to delete. You need to specify this option as `1`.

In order to remove all keys matching the pattern, you also need to run the above command for every master nodes in your cluster.

**NOTE**

1. With this command, you have to delete these keys one-by-one, and that might be very slow. You need to consider re-designing your database, and use **hash-tags** to make keys matching the pattern belong to the same slot. So that you can remove these keys in a single `DEL`.
2. Either `SCAN` or `KEYS` command are inefficient, especially, `KEYS` should not be used in production. You need to consider building an index for these keys.

Comment: I am getting `(error) CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot
` I am using following to delete pattern `hi*` form cluster `redis-cli -u redis://localhost:6379  --scan --pattern 'hi*' | xargs redis-cli -u redis://localhost:6379 DEL`

Comment: @roottraveller As I mentioned in the answer, you need to specify `-L 1` parameter for the `xargs` command

Answer (score 3):

Building on [for_stack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53721482/4256475), you can speed up mass deletion quite a bit using `redis-cli --pipe`, and reduce the performance impact with [`UNLINK`](https://redis.io/commands/unlink) instead of `DEL` if you're using redis 4 or higher.

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern "foo*" | xargs -L 1 echo UNLINK | redis-cli --pipe
```

Output will look something like this:

```
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 107003
```

You do still need to run this against every master node in your cluster. If you have a large number of nodes, it's probably possible to automate the process further by parsing the output of [`CLUSTER NODES`](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-nodes).

Answer (score 1):

`redis-cli` provides a `-c` option to follow `MOVED` redirects.  However, it should be deleted one at a time because you cannot guarantee two keys will be in the same node.

```
redis-cli -h myredis.internal --scan --pattern 'mycachekey::*' | \
  xargs -L 1 -d'\n' redis-cli -h myredis.internal -c del
```

The first part provides a list of keys `--scan` prevents Redis from locking.  `xargs -L 1` runs the command for one entry at a time.  `-d'\n'` disables the processing of quotes so you can have quoted strings like `"SimpleKey[hello world]"` be passed to the command otherwise the spaces will make it have two keys.