# How to delete multiple redis keys with the same pattern in PHP using phpredis?

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

By using [phpredis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis), I have saved some data in pagination like this:

```
   review/itemA/1
   review/itemA/2
```

where `1` and `2` are page numbers. I read in the document that you can use wildcards to retrieve multiple keys.

```
$allKeys = $redis->keys('*');   // all keys will match this.
$keyWithUserPrefix = $redis->keys('user*');
```

But can I delete all the old keys using wildcards as well when someone has posted a new review? Can I do something like:

```
$redis->delete('review/itemA/*'); // or  $redis->delete('review/itemA*')
```

It didn't work however.

Comment: Never use keys command on production environment as it will block the whole DB until the searched key is found. Instead you can use Scan to search specific key for production env.

Answer (score 5):

When using `phpredis`, you can get the prefix (which phpredis automatically prepends everywhere) and delete a pattern of keys that way :

```
<?php
...

$prefix = $redisClient->getOption(Redis::OPT_PREFIX);
$redisClient->delete(array_map(
    function ($key) use ($prefix) {
        return str_replace($prefix, '', $key);
    }, $redisClient->keys('*'))
);
```

Comment: A little improvement to ensure removing the string (prefix) starting to the left: `preg_replace( "/^${prefix}/", '', $key );` in favor of `str_replace`.

Answer (score 4):

No - Redis' `DEL`lete does not accept wildcards, you have to name the keys explicitly. See here for possible directions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23399125/3160475

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `$allKeys = $redis->keys('itemA*');` and looped over the results to delete them one by one. Not sure if that is the best way of doing it.

Comment: Definitely one of the worst ways ;) `KEYS` is an evil command that you should, as a rule, refrain from using (unless thou be brave, fool or both)

Answer (score 2):

With [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis/), I do it like this:

```
    public function delete($key) {
        $keys = $this->client->keys($key);
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            $this->client->del($key);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Predis (`->del`) allows to pass a keys array too.
It works here and is faster than the `del` inside the `foreach`.

```
$prefix = $this->client->getOptions($this->OPT_PREFIX);
$keys = $this->client->keys("$key*");
if ($keys) $this->client->del($keys);
```

Comment: A good answer has a better explanation [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: What's `$prefix = $this->client->getOptions($this->OPT_PREFIX);` here in this code snippet?

Comment: This is a much better solution than iterating over each key. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

```
$bash = 'redis-cli --scan --pattern "' . $path . '*" | xargs -L 1000 redis-cli DEL';

$res = @shell_exec($bash);
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting code-only answers as they do not help the community to improve by learning how to solve a problem. Try to explain why your solution would help with the problem with the code instead.

Comment: It's better to add more context/explanation around code (as opposed to just having a code-only answer) as that makes the answer more useful.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

I just use

```
$redis->delete($redis->keys('*'));
```

It's works fine for me.

Comment: Doesn't this just delete everything since you're matching every key?

Comment: this is a dangerous answer

Comment: Yeah, but you can use mask like some-namespace/*

Comment: `Redis::delete` is deprecated now. It possible use `Redis::del` ?

Answer (score 0):

**There is no wildcard for delete function**.
workaround as follows,

```
// returns total number of keys deleted
function delete($key) {
    if (empty($key)) {  // empty key can delete all
      return false;
    }
    $keys = $redis->keys("$key*");  // keys() function returns array of key strings. `*` wild card pattern can be changed as per need
    if(!$keys) {
        return 0;
    }
    $prefix = $redis->getOption(\Redis::OPT_PREFIX); // keys already have prefix, so we clear until delete finish.
    $redis->setOption(\Redis::OPT_PREFIX, '');
    $count = $redis->del($keys);  // del() function delete array of keys and returns number of keys deleted.
    $redis->setOption(\Redis::OPT_PREFIX, $prefix);

    return $count;
}
```

**Note:** As @Akash Gangrade commented, keys() not advised to use due to performance. you can consider Tags based cache invalidation like https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/cache_invalidation.html#tag-aware-adapters

Answer (score 0):

Using **scan** and **unlink** is best practise as they are non blocking commands unlike *keys* and *delete*

```
# The keys set in redis
/*
1) "review/itemA/5"
2) "review/itemA/2"
3) "review/itemA/3"
4) "review/itemA/1"
5) "review/itemA/4"
*/

/**
 * vars used for scan
 */
$i = null;
$result = [];

/**
 * scan redis using desired pattern
 */
while ($result != 0) {
    $result = $redis->scan($i, 'review/itemA/*');
    if (!empty($result)) {
        $all_keys[] = $result;
    }
}

# Use call_user_func_array to flatten multidimensional array into indexed array
## Scan may return duplicate keys, so use array_unique
$unlink_keys = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $all_keys));

# As of Redis 4.0 use unlink instead of del to stop blocking
$redis->unlink($unlink_keys);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).