# Delete Redis Keys matching a pattern Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, laravel-5.7

I have been searching and tried multiple solution but could got any helping results, I want to clear/delete all keys matching pattern `products:*`.

Following are the things i have tried.

```
Redis::del('products:*');
Redis::del('*products:*');
Redis::del('*products*');
```

But nothing worked.

It is deleting key if i provide exact key name like : `Redis::del('products:2:3:45');`

Key are being generated like this: products:1:4:45

I have read documentation but could find anything regarding my query.

Please help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295488/how-to-delete-multiple-redis-keys-with-the-same-pattern-in-php-using-phpredis. This may solve your problem

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't delete by pattern. But you can get all the keys by this pattern and then delete them:

```php
Redis::del(Redis::keys('products:*'));
```

See more [here](https://redis.io/commands/keys).

Comment: Working like a charm with `Laravel Framework 9.3.0`.

Comment: Not working with Laravel 10.x

Answer (score 4):

I read somewhere that you cannot delete based on wildcard, you need to give the keys explicitly.

There is still a way to grab all keys and then run delete on those keys. I do it using cli like this:

```
redis-cli KEYS "products:*" | xargs redis-cli DEL
```

It fetches all the keys that match the query and run `DEL` on them. 
You can execute this command from Laravel.

In Laravel, fetch all keys and run delete on them using

```
Redis::del(Redis::keys('products:*'));
```

Comment: of course, update your prefix accordingly to support prefixes as well. @MarufAlom

Answer (score 3):

With Laravel 8 it wasn't deleting cause the key has a prefix
so what I did is remove the prefix before passing it to del()

```
$keys = Redis::keys( 'products:*' );

if ( !empty( $keys ) ){
    $keys = array_map(function ($k){
        return str_replace('_prefix_database', '', $k);
    }, $keys);

    Redis::del( $keys );
}
```

i hope this will be helpful for someone

Comment: This worked well in Laravel 7 also. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use the array_map function to go over all the keys in redis and do delete.

```
$redis = new Redis;
$prefix = $redis->getOption(Redis::OPT_PREFIX);
$redis->delete(array_map(
    function ($key) use ($prefix) {
        return str_replace($prefix, '', $key);
    }, $redis->keys('*'))
);
```

Comment: Please share the source when you copy paste from another source

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel8 I use:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->call('queue:flush');

        $arrayFailed        = Redis::connection('horizon')->keys('failed:*');
        $arrayFailedJobs    = Redis::connection('horizon')->keys('failed_jobs');
        $arrayToRemove      = array_merge($arrayFailed, $arrayFailedJobs);

        $arrayMap = array_map(function ($k) {
            return str_replace(config('horizon.prefix'), '', $k);
        }, $arrayToRemove);
        Redis::connection('horizon')->del($arrayMap);

        $this->line('');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 10x:
Let's assume we have a Redis instance and connection established via Predis client:

```
$client = new Predis\Client();
$client->del(Redis::keys("products*")
```

I think the Redis::keys() method gets the keys with the prefix so the Redis::del() includes the prefix again the second time.