# Get sizes of all sorted sets with a given prefix

Tags: redis

I got several sorted sets with a common prefix (`itemmovements:`) in Redis.

I know we can use [ZCOUNT](http://redis.io/commands/ZCOUNT) to get the number of items for a single (sorted set) key like this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zcount itemmovements:8 0 1000000000
(integer) 23
```

(I am able to do this, since I know the range of the item scores.)

How to run this in a loop for all keys prefixed `itemmovements:`?

Taking hint from [How to atomically delete keys matching a pattern using Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis) I tried this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> EVAL "return redis.call('zcount', unpack(redis.call('keys', ARGV[1])), 0, 1000000000)" 0 itemmovements:*
(integer) 150
```

but as you can see it just returns a single number (which happens to be the size of `itemmovements:0`, the first value returned by `keys`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I did not understand what that lua code in EVAL was doing. The code below works fine:

```
eval "local a = {}; for _,k in ipairs(redis.call('keys', 'itemmovements:*')) do table.insert(a, k); table.insert(a, redis.call('zcount', k, 0, 1000000000)); end; return a" 0
```

Comment: Note that using `KEYS` is potentially dangerous and shouldn't be done on production.

Comment: @ItamarHaber: thanks and agreed. I had only 20 keys with that prefix so this is fine for my case.

Comment: The command-that-must-not-be-named is dangerous even if you don't have any keys with that prefix