# Redis cli delete multiple keys

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, phpredis, redis-cli

I have installed Redis in centos and I have multiple keys of redis like this,

```
Product:<id>:<url>
```

How can I delete all `Product:*:*`  with CLI ?

Redis version : 3.2.4 [ Latest I guess ]

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to atomically delete keys matching a pattern using Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis)

Answer (score 37):

Using the `redis-cli` tool, you can do the following:

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern 'Product:*:*' | xargs redis-cli DEL
```

Comment: Not too sure why that failed for me but switched to this and it worked:
`redis-cli keys '*' | grep Product | xargs -i redis-cli del {}`

Comment: @kakoma "failed" how?

Comment: My bad @Itamar. Just realized I'd typed a wrong pattern *face palm* All is well. Thanks for the tip! Upvoted

Comment: No problem, I had to undergo cosmetic surgery to remove the impression of my palm from my face <- so many years doing it :)

Comment: it sounds good but if you have more than one db or thousands or millions of keys I released my searches result below as answer

Comment: You can also chose server with `-u` and database with `-n` parameter like `redis-cli -u redis://redisserver:6379 -n 1 --scan --pattern 'Product:*:*''`

Comment: I am getting `(error) CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot
` I am using following to delete pattern `hi*` form cluster `redis-cli -u redis://localhost:6379  --scan --pattern 'hi*' | xargs redis-cli -u redis://localhost:6379 DEL`

Comment: I need to use xargs -L 1 else it won't resolve the each line key result.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with redis 2.6.0, you can use LUA scripts.

You should use this variant over the `SCAN` | `XARGS` variant because it's much faster.

The following script works also for a large amount of keys.

1. open your redis-cli

```
redis-cli -p somePort -a somePassword
```

2. Replace somePattern with your pattern e.g. `*cars*` (remember it's not regex)

```
EVAL "for _,k in ipairs(redis.call('keys','somePattern')) do redis.call('del',k) end" 0
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no built-in command for that. You have to use the `SCAN` command to get all keys that match the pattern, then use the `DEL` command to remove these keys.

```
// scan from cursor 0 to get the next cursor and keys
SCAN 0 match Product:*:*
// next_cursor, Product:x1:y1, Product:x2:y2, ...
DEL Product:x1:y1 Product:x2:y2 ...
// scan from the next cursor until it return 0
SCAN next_cursor match Product:*:*
```

Another solution is to use a `HASH` to save keys of this pattern:

```
// set key value
HSET Products Product:<id>:<url> value
// remove a single key
HDEL Products Product:<id>:<url>
// remove all keys
DEL Products
```

Comment: Can you give me example to scan and then delete ?

Comment: @JohnFG I update the answer. For more details on `SCAN`, check the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

```
-n <db>            Database number
```

shell: `redis-cli -n 1 --scan --pattern prefix:* | xargs redis-cli -n 1 del`

Answer (score 2):

put all keys you want to delete inside keylist.txt file then:

```
cat keylist.txt | while read rediskey; do echo "Deleting $rediskey" && redis-cli -c -h 'hostname' -p XXXX -a 'XXXXXX' UNLINK $rediskey; done
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that.

1. https://gist.github.com/ddre54/0a4751676272e0da8186  Is not
   recommended on production server since it is using KEYS keyword
2. Using ioredis (https://github.com/luin/ioredis#streamify-scanning) which supports Redis >= 2.6.12 and (Node.js >= 6)

If you want to follow second example just do following steps:

1. Install node js >=6
2. Create folder and inside it  install ioredis by running following command:

   npm install ioredis
3. Inside that folder create redis.js file with following content

   ```
   module.exports.redisDel = function(key) {
   console.log("del started for key: ", key);
   var Redis = require("ioredis");

   var redis = new Redis({
       port: 6379, // Redis port
       host: "192.168.93.27", // Redis host
       family: 4, // 4 (IPv4) or 6 (IPv6)
       password: "SetCorrectPassword"
   });

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

       var stream = redis.scanStream({
           // only returns keys following the pattern of "key"
           match: key,
           // returns approximately 100 elements per call
           count: 100
       });

       stream.on('data', function (resultKeys) {
           if (resultKeys.length) {
               console.log(resultKeys)
               redis.del(resultKeys); //from version 4 use unlink instead of del
           }
           else {
               console.log("nothing found");
           }
       });
       stream.on('end', function (resultKeys) {
           console.log("end");
           resolve()
       })
   })
   ```

   }
4. Run script by passing desired key (in our case yourKey*)

node -e 'require(\"./redis\").redisDel(\"yourKey*\")'

Answer (score 0):

For Windows cmd.exe command interpreter, use `FOR` with /F:

```
FOR /F %I IN ('redis-cli KEYS Product:*:*') DO redis-cli DEL %I
```

If you have backquote commands enabled (not likely) you might need to use backquotes instead of apostrophes.

Source: `FOR /?`

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested above by Itamar works perfectly.

but in case you need to provide authentication in your redis setup when deleting and need to select the host in which to run the del command, you can add password, port and host as follows:-

```
redis-cli -a {password} --scan --pattern "*{your pattern}*"  -h {hostip} -p {port}| xargs redis-cli -a {password} -h {hostip} -p {port} del
```

This solved my issue, hope its useful for you as well..