# How to fuel up used_memory in Redis?

Tags: redis

I have a Redis cluster with maxmemory_human 6.05 G and used_memory_human: 4.62M

I want to fuel up this used_memory_human with dump data so i would have 2G of used_memory_human

How could i do that?

Comment: Do you want to generate some test data?

Comment: Yes, i want to generate some test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Populate

```
eval "for i=0,(1024*1024*20) do redis.call('set','testData:'..i,'1234567890') end" 0
```

> used_memory_human:1.81G

### Clean

```
eval "for i=0,(1024*1024*20) do redis.call('del','testData:'..i) end" 0
```

> used_memory_human:574.41K

Comment: It runs for about 45 sec on my machine.

Comment: Note: this is only valid for non-clustered deployments

Comment: How to keep these cache data for like 5 hours?

Comment: @TheOne Change the call part to `redis.call('setex','testData:'..i,5*60*60,'1234567890')`

Comment: Hey @Imaskar , somehow i got error after executing command. It said: Connection refused.  The odd thing is: i tried this command for like 50 times, only 1 time worked.

Comment: I meant to modify eval with this call. It would be `eval "for i=0,(1024*1024*20) do redis.call('setex','testData:'..i,5*60*60,'1234567890') end" 0`

Comment: There is also a limit how long LUA can execute until timeout. When you get an error do you wait for a long time before it appears? Then run `config set lua-time-limit 120000`

Comment: @Imaskar yup, of course i added end" 0 at the end of redis.call('setex','testData:'..i,5*60*60,'1234567890')  and it was perfectly same as your ↑ command. I'll give it a try with set lua time.

Answer (score 3):

There's a built-in debug command for that.

`debug populate 2000000 testkey 1000`

This will create 2 million 1kb string keys.

```
> debug populate 2000000 testkey 1000
OK
(2.52s)
> scan 0
1) "65536"
2)  1) "testkey:1637732"
    2) "testkey:510112"
    3) "testkey:1313139"
    4) "testkey:34729"
    5) "testkey:734989"
    6) "testkey:996052"
    7) "testkey:223126"
    8) "testkey:1578003"
    9) "testkey:1335698"
   10) "testkey:1151100"
> info memory
# Memory
used_memory:2185489192
used_memory_human:2.04G
used_memory_rss:2247540736
used_memory_rss_human:2.09G
used_memory_peak:2185571088
used_memory_peak_human:2.04G
```

Comment: It there a matching command to clean it, not flushing whole database?

Comment: Ah, I think your server version must be quite old. You can run `INFO` command to check.

Comment: # Server
redis_version:3.2.4

Comment: I went to the github tag, and version 3.2.4 has `populate` subcommand of DEBUG so not sure where your ERR is coming from.

Comment: @Imaskar Deleting keys by pattern is answered here, you can use this if you don't want to `flushall`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis

Comment: @nnog yeah,  I know how to do that. But debug populate is much faster than iterating,  so I wondered if there is a matching fast deletion.

Comment: @Imaskar Not that I know of. You could populate a different empty DB (`SELECT`) then do `FLUSHDB` if you want to quickly test growing and shrinking.

Comment: @The One Just a thought: `DEBUG` and `CONFIG` etc. commands are often renamed to disable them on managed instances, so this is probably why you can't use it on your 3.2.4 instance

Comment: Got it. Thanks @nnog