# How to delete Redis keys?

Tags: redis

My Redis key has got special characters. I tried the following commands but no use.

```
redis-cli  keys *ueryLikesApp*
1) "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x1dqueryLikesApps04ea56ff2567012"
```

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern "*Likes*"
```

No data found

```
redis-cli keys  "*Likes*"|xargs redis-cli  del
```

No data found

how to delete these redis key?

Comment: Try this `redis-cli --raw keys "*Likes*" | xargs redis-cli del` ?

Answer (score 0):

As in [How to atomically delete keys matching a pattern using Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis), this will work, using Lua scripting:

```
redis-cli EVAL "return redis.call('del', unpack(redis.call('keys', ARGV[1])))" 0 "*Likes*"
```

And if you have thousands of keys

```
EVAL "local keys = redis.call('keys', ARGV[1]) \n for i=1,#keys,5000 do \n redis.call('del', unpack(keys, i, math.min(i+4999, #keys))) \n end \n return keys" 0 "*Likes*"
```