# delete redis keys when clearing cache

Tags: redis, symfony5

project configuration : symfony 5.

I configured my cache to use redis, in `config\packages\cache.yml` like this

```
framework:
    cache:
        prefix_seed: myAppPrefix_
        app: cache.adapter.redis
        system: cache.adapter.filesystem
        default_redis_provider: '%env(REDIS_URL)%'
```

When i run `php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev`, redis keys are not deleted and they are not expired.

The `cache:clear` command is not supposed to remove or make the keys expired ?

I can i delete all my keys, matching my App prefix ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you check redis with `dbsize` or `info memory` ? probably your config is missing (not familiar with symfony). You may try `redis-cli monitor` to see the executed methods. If there is not `flushall` or `flushdb` then you need to check the your redis configuration.

Comment: i don't want a flushall because redis is share with other applications. I must delete only the key matching my prefix. I just don't understand if symfony is supposed to do something or not in redis when i run cache:clear. Does it works for you ?

Comment: I think it may not have that feature(laravel doesn't) but you may check the answers posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis - i used them many times for similar cases to yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find any references confirming that cache:clear is supposed to clear redis keys linked to my configuration.

Finaly, i created a command (injecting "AdapterInterface") to clean them with that code :

```
public function __construct(AdapterInterface $cache)
{
    ...
    $this->cache= $cache;
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $this->redis->clear();
}
```

**Be careful**, on windows it doesn't works because redis version is empty in RedisTrait:356