# Laravel: How do you cache:clear your application when you use Redis Clusters?

Tags: laravel, redis

#### Short:

In Redis Clusters, you are only allowed to use one Database.

What happens if you call the command `php artisian cache:clear`?

#### Details:

Normally, when you are calling the command

```
php artisian cache:clear
```

your session and queue Redis database are not deleted, because of the use of different databases:

```
    'default' => [
        'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
    ],
```

You can see that Redis uses the cache connection and cache connection of Redis has set the database to 1 by default.

Now if I want to migrate to Redis Clusters, this part is getting tricky. Because Redis Clusters only **allows you to have one database.**

According to this [blog post](https://aregsar.com/blog/2020/my-laravel-redis-configuration/) my configuration has to look like this:

```
//the redis driver
'redis' => [
    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis',
    ],
    //the `default` connection of the redis driver
    //Note: The Laravel Redis facade is hard coded to use this connection unless its connection is explicitly specified
    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => '0',
        `prefix` => `d:`
    ],
    //the `cache` connection of the redis driver
    'cache' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => '0',
        `prefix` => `c:`
    ],
    //the `queue` connection of the redis driver
    'queue' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => '0',
        `prefix` => 'q:',
    ],
    //the `session` connection of the redis driver
    'session' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => '0',
        #since config/session.php does not have an app level prefix we can change
        #this prefx to `myapp:s:` if we share redis server between apps
        `prefix` => `s:`
    ],
],
```

As you might see, the `database` is set to 0. What happens when I call the command `php artisian cache:clear`?

If you look at the official documentations https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redis#configuration and scroll down to the part: `Configuring Clusters` you see that database is also set to 0. However, one thing is unclear. It uses the array key `clusters`.

So my question that arises with that: How do you cache:clear your application when you use Redis Clusters?

Comment: Do you mean how do you clear cache without deleting any session or queue data ? "Redis Cluster does not support multiple databases like the stand alone version of Redis. There is just database 0 and the SELECT command is not allowed." Because of that it will be impossible to delete with a single command without deleting at all.

Comment: @Ersoy exactly this is what I mean. So you are saying it is just not possible. You are not able to delete the cache with redis clusters without deleting sessions and queue data, right?

Comment: Yes. I think you need to run some delete commands(on different nodes) with prefixes or use different redis instances for session and queue.

Comment: @Ersoy cache:clear fires the command 'flushdb'. Not sure how you can delete only with specific prefixes. Could you point me documentation or something? But thanks nonetheless!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis there are some working examples under this question. I used something like this `redis-cli KEYS "*:foo:*" | xargs redis-cli DEL`

Comment: @PhilippMochine I am facing the exact issue , how did u fix this ?