# Delete Redis keys matching a pattern

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redisclient

I am using Redis hash set to store data in the following format:

```
hset b1.b2.b3 name test
```

Now I want to delete this key so I am using the following format:

```
del b1.b2.*
```

But it not working so how I delete the Redis key using a pattern?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to atomically delete keys matching a pattern using Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Redis does not provide any method to delete bulk keys. But redis-cli along with xargs can be used to achieve what you are trying to do. See the commands below:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset b1.b2.b3 name test
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall b1.b2.b3
1) "name"
2) "test"
$ redis-cli --scan --pattern b1.b2.* | xargs redis-cli del
(integer) 1
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall b1.b2.b3
(empty list or set)
```

We are scanning redis for a pattern using '--scan' and the output is given to redis-cli again using the xargs method whcih combines all the keys in the scan result and finally we delete all of them using 'del' command.

Comment: how we can implement this using Redis node js module.

Comment: Please accept the answer or edit your question. It doesn’t say you have to implement this in nodejs

Comment: As an addendum to this, I would recommend using [`unlink`](https://redis.io/commands/unlink/) instead of [`del`](https://redis.io/commands/del/). The key difference is that an `unlink` command is non-blocking.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to do this via the `redis-cli` in bulk, you could consider expiring all the keys based on a specified pattern:

```
EVAL 'for i, name in ipairs(redis.call("KEYS", <pattern>)) do redis.call("EXPIRE", name, 1); end' 0
```

Effectively it sets the expiration to 1 second so this should do the trick!

Comment: Works great! Should be a built-in command, glarily missing for some reason... they got every other damn thing in that api, tho!

Answer (score 0):

In my case this command worked like a charm:

```
redis-cli -a myPass keys "*myKeyword*" | xargs -I% redis-cli -a myPass del "%"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it using the pattern above @Ankit answered.

you can do a `SCAN` and then delete the keys until nothing left (cursor is 0)

https://redis.io/commands/scan