# Nodejs Redis delete all keys including its fields by specific prefix

Tags: node.js, redis

I have the following piece of code that I am using to delete records from Redis

```
public hdel(hash: string, field?: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!field) {
            this.store.del(hash, (err, response) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }
                resolve(response);
            });
            return;
        }
        this.store.hdel(hash, field, (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(response);
        });
    });
}
```

If field is not given, I will be deleting all fields.

`store` is just a `RedisClient`.

I am using the [Redis package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)

I am looking to delete all records that starts with the prefix I give, for example I have the following code:

```
async deleteSessionFiles(sessionId: string) {
    const path = SessionPathResolver.resolveSessionAllFiles(sessionId);
    await this.cacheService.hdel(path);
}
```

This piece of code generates a redis ALL record path by session ID by using `*` at the end of the path, for example `sessions/gHs46f/files/*`

```
static resolveSessionAllFiles = (sessionId: string) => {
    return `sessions/${sessionId}/files/*`;
}
```

and then I am using the function I provided at the beginning of the question.

However, unlike the `KEYS prefix/*` command which knows to give you all records of a given prefix, this won't delete all records, not even one.
What is the right way to do such operation with this package or in general?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Redis` `SCAN` command to fetch keys by a curser and use `DEL` to delete all fetched keys, and iterate it over the keys without bad effects of `KEYS *`

Read more about [`SCAN` command here](https://redis.io/commands/scan)

And [Here an example](https://github.com/redis/node-redis#scan-iterator) of using `SCAN` in `redis package`

Also, [see this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324) there is lots of good ways to delete in batch

Comment: There is no way to do this in one call? I knew of this way, however I thought there could be a more efficient approach to this?

Comment: @benberizovsky you can use `Lua` code like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16974060/2882619)

Answer (score 0):

Delete keys by pattern Redis nodejs

```
 for await (const key of cacheConnection.scanIterator({
      TYPE: 'string', // `SCAN` only
      MATCH: `*${somekeypattern}*`,
      COUNT: 100
    })) {
      // use the key!
      await cacheConnection.del(key);
    }
```